# How to fit separate variance-covariance matrices in MCMCglmm

Tags: r, matrix

I tried to correlate behaviour (activity)  and metabolism (resBMR) in animal. I used mixed model analysis and package MCMCglmm.  I set trial and season as a fixed factors. Moreover we have 2 other fixed effects: SEX and RESP. RESP stands for type of response to winter: R, NR and HR.

I prepared a bivariate mixed model. This model should allow me to fit separate variance-covariance matrices according to RESP (3 levels). 
The code goes like this:

```
prior<-list(R=list(R1=list(V=diag(2), nu=1.002),R2=list(V=diag(2), nu=1.002),R3=list(V=diag(2), nu=1.002)),G=list(G1=list(V=diag(2), nu=1.002),G2=list(V=diag(2), nu=1.002),G3=list(V=diag(2), nu=1.002)))

RESP <- MCMCglmm (cbind(resBMR,activity)

~trait-1+trait:trial + trait:SEX + trait:RESP + trait:season,

random=~us(at.level(RESP,"NR"):trait):ID+us(at.level(RESP,"R"):trait):ID+us(at.level(RESP, "HR"):trait):ID,

rcov = us(at.level(RESP,"NR"):trait):units+us(at.level(RESP,"R"):trait):units +us(at.level(RESP, "HR"):trait):units,

family=c("gaussian","gaussian"),prior=prior,data=data)
```

The model worked but then I want to calculate intercept-intercept correlation of dependent traits as follows:

```
cor_int_intR <- RESP$VCV[,"at.level(RESP,"NR"):traitactivity:at.level(RESP, "NR"):traitresBMR.ID"] 

/sqrt(RESP$VCV[,"at.level(RESP,"NR"):traitactivity:at.level(RESP,"NR"):traitactivity.ID"]

*RESP$VCV[,"at.level(RESP,"NR"):traitresBMR:at.level(RESP,"NR"):traitresBMR.ID"])
```

And I obtained the error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in
>   "cor_int_intR<-RESP$VCV[,"at.level(RESP,"NR"

I checked the VCV of the model and it looks exactly like that. But when I wrote NR in quotation, it change colour and it tell me "unexpected token 'NR' "

Any idea what wrong is with that?

EDIT: Here is my data frame example:

```html
ID RESP SEX trial season resBMR activity
1 HR male  1 lato 0.250052984 0.3536
1 HR male  2 lato NA -0.15325
1 HR male  3 zima 0.239365502 1.63709
1 HR male  4 zima NA 0.90206
4 R male  1 lato 0.184630641 0.72714
4 R male  2 lato NA 0.9956
4 R male  3 zima 0.222260753 0.4192
4 R male  4 zima NA -1.78506
5 NR male  1 lato 0.269151827 -0.2999
5 NR male  2 lato NA -0.19877
5 NR male  3 zima 0.22583699 0.95727
5 NR male  4 zima NA -0.76502
6 HR male  1 lato 0.244090325 0.18667
6 HR male  2 lato NA -0.42045
6 HR male  3 zima 0.261126729 0.13811
6 HR male  4 zima NA -0.70864
7 NR female 1 lato 0.252336196 0.78315
7 NR female 2 lato NA 1.12088
7 NR female 3 zima 0.19488432 0.30034
7 NR female 4 zima NA -0.95369
8 NR female 1 lato 0.216474311 -0.89225
8 NR female 2 lato NA -0.23443
8 NR female 3 zima 0.241733394 0.79699
8 NR female 4 zima NA -0.41397
9 NR male  1 lato 0.233164752 -0.11484
9 NR male  2 lato NA -1.26982
9 NR male  3 zima 0.258378951 0.35827
9 NR male  4 zima NA -1.32658
10 R male  1 lato 0.233973797 -0.24418
10 R male  2 lato NA -0.37234
10 R male  3 zima 0.283488877 1.05007
10 R male  4 zima NA -1.62183
11 NR male  1 lato 0.247344964 -1.27324
```

Comment: `Error: unexpected symbol` usually means syntax error. In your case, you are mixing double quotes. Try replacing `"NR"` with `'NR'` and see if it works.

Comment: I should write that I tried it before.
I obtained:
 Error in `[.default`(RESP$VCV, , "at.level(RESP,'NR'):traitactivity:at.level(RESP, 'NR'):traitresBMR.ID") : 
  subscript out of bounds

Comment: I tried running your example and it seems you are missing `~` in `rcov = us(` part. And after that I get `'data' argument is of the wrong type`, so your example is not reproducible, unfortunately.

Comment: I added an example of my data frame. I used the csv. file. And I set ID, SEX, RESP and season as factor.

Answer (score 0):

I managed with that issue. Maybe it is not the most elegant way but I simply changed the name of columns in VCV and I used new names in code. It works!